# concurrent process -- bash scripting - for FILE in $(ls *.ext) do echo $FILE >> file_list -- out of order

Tags: bash, for-loop, ls, cat

Answered by using

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

after the shebang -- b/c the script is being run in a non-interactive terminal - and I don't have this sourced in my .bash_profile

This means that code executing in an interactive terminal may behave differently than code executing in a non-interactive terminal... Now for the question at hand...

I'm (was) trying to take two files, once they appear in a folder, and put the names into a 'file_list'

Then file_list will be iterated over and the files will be processed one by one, top to bottom.

one has to process before the other one, and this is done by having its date earlier - so by using 'ls' - the one appearing sooner alphabetically, is the first one written to file_list.

The file names are:

```
foo_bar_09172013.foo
afoo_bar_09172013_ZERO.foo
```

(normally the one prefixed with the letter 'a' will have an earlier date, and no letter 'a', so I'm counting on that to put it alphabetically before the other file, and thus processed first) (its date is the same right now, so I'm prefixing it with the letter 'a' to sort it for now)

file_list is being written as:

```
foo_bar_09172013.foo
afoo_bar_09172013_ZERO.foo
```

by the program which is run through a concurrent process --

If I run this program from the shell, it runs correctly... and lists the files as

```
afoo_bar_09172013_ZERO.foo
foo_bar_09172013.foo
```

--Firstly, I should use while read instead of for i -- but I can't right now.

--Secondly, the only thing I've seen so far that deals w/ this is 'interactive' vs 'noninteractive' terminals...

The script seems to execute normally sometimes - other times the files are listed backwards.  I can't figure out why.

The script:

```
for FILE in $(ls *.foo 2> /dev/null)

do
  echo $FILE >> file_list
done
```

--

TL;DR -- once I vi file_list, the files are not listed alphabetically - why???  It works if I run this directly from the terminal window - it does not if I run this as a concurrent program in another application.

edit: this is the full code now after chepner's change - which doesn't work --

```
check_for_files()
{

mv $fooSHARE/*.foo $INFILEDIR
cd $INFILEDIR
chmod 777 *.foo
ls *.foo


rm -f file_list 2> /dev/null
for FILE in *.foo


do
      echo $FILE >> $INFILEDIR/file_list
done
}
```

Comment: There's no need to use `ls`, which will not work properly if any of the matching file names contain whitespace. Simply use `for FILE in *.foo` instead. The order of the files is determined by the current locale.

Comment: Awesome, what if though the files are out of order in their 'current locale'?  What determines the order they're in?  Is it always alphabetical?

Also, none of the matching files contain whitespace -- and they never will.  Could _ be causing the discrepancy?

Comment: It's usually something like alphabetical. Usually, the only noticeable difference is how numbers (10 is numerically larger, but lexicographically smaller, than 2) and case differences (does "Z" come before or after "a"?) are treated. Check the value of the `LANG` environment variable.

Comment: Then this won't work on January first when my file is 

foo_bar_12312013.foo 
and
foo_bar_01312014.foo

The latter file will process first

Comment: I recommend using year/month/day order for dates, which sort correctly when treated as strings, as specified by ISO 8601.

Comment: I just tried this, and even tho the second file is prefixed with the letter a, file_list is still being populated out of alphabetical order.

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of the fact that the globs in bash return the list sorted alphabetically [[Ref]](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Filename-Expansion). So you can do this to create the sorted list:

```
printf "%s\n" *.foo >> file_list
```

Comment: but the ls command already returns the list sorted alphabetically.  It just doesn't when I run this from the concurrent program.  

In fact, I think if I put (ls -r *.foo) - it will work as intended.  But why is this?  Is there an answer that gives insight as to why this is happening to me?

Comment: @user2144835 What do you mean by "concurent program"? Perhaps there are more than one processes writing to file at a time?

Comment: I'm using an application to run a program, that program will run this script.  There are not other applications running this program / this script.  *edit - and there are no other processes writing to this file

Comment: @user2144835 This is strange then. I don't know why you could get a different order if you run the script directly or through another application.

Comment: I get literally different results when I just type this command in, or when the command is read from a file.